# Start service using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I'm working with c# and try to run process using vb script.File is working fine when try to run `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);` it works fine. I'm using window service when try to run using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);` it doesn't run my whole script i don't know it happening i have no idea why it is happening ? i also used `wait` command but still script file not execute completely
any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to debug the issue further, as it's almost impossible to tell what the problem is with the provided information.

You say "it doesn't run my whole script".  Does this mean that it runs part of the script?  At what point does the script stop executing?  What statement is the script supposed to execute at that point?

Without any other information about the problem, my thought is that this might be a user context or permission issue.  Services generally run under a system account, whereas applications that you launch yourself run under your own user context.

If this script is accessing a network share, then it might execute fine under your own user context, assuming that you have already accessed that network share and provided credentials, but attempting to access that network share from a service might fail, because the service is not running under your user context.